# How to add an array inside array using variable in form helper

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have form helper in codeigniter like this

```php
<?=form_input('institute_name', $letter->institute_code.' - '.$letter->institute_name, array('id'=>'institute_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Pilih Institut'))?>
```

And have variable that will set the field into readonly

`$readonly->institute_code` that has value "readonly"

Is it possible to throw this variable inside array as because when I just add the variable like this

```php
<?=form_input('institute_name', $letter->institute_code.' - '.$letter->institute_name, array('id'=>'institute_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Pilih Institut', $readonly->institute_code ))?>
```

the result will add `0="readonly"` in page-source.
I want the result to become `'readonly'='readonly'`

Comment: Did my post helped you?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

create variable that contain array, then add 1 line if and then put the arrays inside form input helper.

```php
$arrays = array('id'=>'institute_name','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Pilih Institut')
$readonly->draft_file==1?$arrays['readonly'] = 'readonly':'';
echo form_input('institute_name', $letter->institute_code.' - '.$letter->institute_name, $arrays)
```